# Why is my unsigned long long int which is within 8 bytes is outputting an error?

Tags: c++, mingw

I am using the MinGW c++ compiler and trying to execute the following line:
`unsigned long long unlli = 18446744073709551615;`
the range of the unsigned long long int it `0-18446744073709551615`
I don't understand why I am not able to make full use of it, even if I go below `18446744073709551615` it still outputs the error:

```
.\main.cpp:34:32: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
   34 |     unsigned long long unlli = 18446744073709551615;
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(edit: sorry, thought I had included the error)

I don't know if I am being dumb of have messed something up somewhere, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what error? Please include it in the question

Comment: Is this clearer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/598dd3297674279c ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, not really

Comment: Sorry, by bad :P

Comment: it is an unsigned long long variable, not an unsigned long variable

Comment: @xXdesertwolfXx Make it an `unsigned`constant: `18446744073709551614u`, the warning goes away then: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9126dfe0f0dad326

Comment: don't add ANSWERED or SOLVED to the title. In searches it is already visible if a question does have an answer

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without suffix the type of integer literals is ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)):

```
int
long int
long long int (since C++11)
```

You get the warning because the value is too large to fit into a `long long int`. Use the `ull` suffix for an `unsigned long long`:

```
unsigned long long unlli = 18446744073709551615ull;
```

Comment: so would i have to use `ull::long long = 18446744073709551615;`? i am very new to c++ so I don't really understand

Comment: ok, thankyou it makes a lot more sense now!